# <Link> tag not opening link, but shows in html

Tags: reactjs

I use the `<Link>` tag on `logo` and `callToActions` to direct the user to the respective pages, but they do not seem to responsive although it does show up in the inspector.

Here is the code of my `Header` component:

```
const Header = props => {
return (
    <header className='header'>
        <div className='wrap'>
            <div className='logo'>
                <Link to='/'>
                    <img src={Logo}/>
                </Link>
            </div>

            <div className='callToActions'>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to='/registration'>
                            Register
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the inspector tool:
[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yayJ2.jpg)

I tried running on different browsers, it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:**

Here's the `app.js` where `Router` has been used:

```
function App() 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render = {() => (
          <HomepageLayout>
            <Homepage />
          </HomepageLayout>
        )} />
        <Route path="/registration" render={() => (
          <MainLayout>
            <Registration />
          </MainLayout>
        )} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Edit 2:**

I apologize, the `BrowserRouter` is at `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I was following a Youtube tutorial: https://youtu.be/_lS9zphSBxk?t=1627

Comment: Can you provide a link for testing? I could definitely help you that way.

Comment: Are you using `Link` inside a `Router`.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh yes, I also edited the post to mention the code

Comment: The provided code does not contain a `<Router>` (does have a `<Route>` though). Is there one in the index file that wraps `<App>`?

Comment: I see routes, but no router.

Comment: @Eliza You should have `BrowserRouter` or any other provided `Router` wrapper around your `Switch` Component. Then only Link will work.

Comment: <BrowserRouter> <Switch>...</Switch> </BrowserRouter>

Comment: Please provide a minimal-reproducible-example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @HenryWoody yes, there is.